# Click event on react element find null object

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have got tabs with the class

```
class Onglet extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this)
    }
    handleClick (event){
        Onglets.changeOnglet(this.props.name);
    }

    render (){
        return (
            <li onClick={this.handleClick}><a>{this.props.title}</a></li>
        );
    }
}
```

and when I want to change the tab I will use the name giving in props like this

```
<Onglet name="demandes" title="Mes demandes"/>
```

but when when I try to click, it say the object is null but I can see that it has been created before with it props

```
Object {name: "demandes", title: "Mes demandes"}
```

If I'm not completely clear, thanks to ask me, and I will trying to explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite `handleClick` like this -

```
    handleClick = (event) => {
        Onglets.changeOnglet(this.props.name);
    }
```

OR, change the `<li onClick={this.handleClick}>` code to -

```
<li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
```